# PIP does not work when I try to install pygame

Tags: python, installation, pip, pygame

I tried to install `pygame` with the command `pip install pygame` and there is an error message:

> Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
>
> Current thread 0x000019c8 (most recent call first):

Comment: Are you trying to install this on an antique Python 2 system?  pygame doesn't support less than Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the pygame installer. Try uninstalling and reinstalling pygame using the following commands:

```
pip uninstall pygame
pip install pygame
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running `pip install wheel`, `pip install encoding`, and then `pip install pygame`

Alternatively, check your environment variables to make sure your modules are findable [Fatal Python error on Windows 10 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512817/fatal-python-error-on-windows-10-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-encodings)

Comment: it doesn't even work and I have version 3.10.8 of python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956888/doesnt-python-3-10-support-pygame looks like it may be a compatability issue, if your env variables look good

Comment: `pip install encoding` and `pip install encodings` cannot work; 1st, there are no such packages at PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/encoding/ and https://pypi.org/project/encodings/ — error 404; 2nd, it's a package from the standard library: https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib/encodings